# Regex creating an empty group?

Tags: regex, parsing, grouping

I have written a rexeg string to parse a log into a set of groups, however it is creating an empty group when an optional section of the log is present. I have marked the section optional using `?` in regex, but it still seems to create an empty group.

Here are the two regular expressions I've tried;

```
([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}) - (DMG|KILL):[ ]+(.*?)\[(.*?)\] (?:damaged|killed) (.*?) \[(.*?)\](?: for (\d{0,9}) dmg)?

([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}) - (DMG|KILL):[ ]+(.*?)\[(.*?)\] (?:damaged|killed) (.*?) \[(.*?)\](?: for (\d{0,9})? dmg)?
```

My second regular expression has a question mark after the end of the `(\d{0,9})`, as I thought there was the possibility that this was creating the empty group, but it doesn't seem to be that. I am parsing a string along the lines of the following;

```
00:00.00 - DMG:     Player [group] damaged Victim [group] for 130 dmg
00:00.00 - KILL:     Player [group] killed Victim [group]
```

It is when parsing the last line (no `for X damage`) an empty group is created at the end.

I apologise for the monstrous regex.

---

It has been shown that my regular expression works fine, thanks to @[Sniffer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439667/sniffer) in the comments section. It can be seen [here](http://regex101.com/r/wS2cL9) that it works as expected, however when implemented into my application, it does not.

When in my application, `matcher.group(7)` (the last group) on a 'KILL' line (one that does not include 'dmg' returns null, and matcher.groupCount() returns 7 instead of 6, meaning it finds an empty group at the end. My regex is as follows;

```
private static final Pattern match = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}) - (DMG|KILL):[ \t]+(.*?)\\[(.*?)\\] (?:damaged|killed) (.*?) \\[(.*?)\\](?: for (\\d{0,9}) dmg)?");
```

And this is the code I am using to match the pattern;

```
Matcher matcher = DamageEvent.match.matcher(tLine);

if (matcher.matches())
{
    int matches = matcher.groupCount();
    if (matches < 6 || matches > 7)
    {
        System.err.println("Invalid line: " + tLine);
        return null;
    }
    String time = matcher.group(1);
    String type = matcher.group(2);
    String attackerName = matcher.group(3);
    String attackerGroupString = matcher.group(4);
    String victimName = matcher.group(5);
    String victimGroupString = matcher.group(6);
    String damage = "0";

    System.out.println(matches);

    if (matches == 7) // This results as 'true'
    {
        damage = matcher.group(7); // Damage is set to null :(
    }

}
```

Comment: Language or tool you are using ?

Comment: In the end I will be using Java's Regex Pattern and Matcher, but for now I am viewing the groups created using [this tool](http://www.softlion.com/webTools/RegExpTest/default.aspx).

Comment: I have tested your regular expression [**here**](http://regex101.com/r/wS2cL9) and everything is working fine.

Comment: Oh wow, must be a dud regex tester then, or one that just works differently. Thanks, case closed I guess!

Comment: I have undeleted this, as there is still a problem with a "null" group in Java. I will update the answer to include my current code.

Comment: Why don't you just use named groups, and then the group index is irrelevant?

Comment: Can you just check that matcher.group(7) is not null before assigning it to the "damage" variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is by design, e.g. per [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29):

*If the match was successful but the group specified failed to match any part of the input sequence, then **null** is returned.*

So the following [example](http://ideone.com/vdbAlq):

```
    Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("(t1)(t2)?(t3)").matcher("t1t3");
    if(m1.matches()) {
        for(int g=1;g<=m1.groupCount();g++){
            System.out.println("Group "+g+": "+m1.group(g));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("--------------");
    Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("(t1)()(t3)").matcher("t1t3");
    if(m2.matches()) {
        for(int g=1;g<=m2.groupCount();g++){
            System.out.println("Group "+g+": "+m2.group(g));
        }
    }
```

will output:

```
Group 1: t1
Group 2: null
Group 3: t3
--------------
Group 1: t1
Group 2: 
Group 3: t3
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it ignore an optional group? Or do I just check for null?

Comment: I see that it's part of group()'s design to return null if nothing is matched in the group, which I guess is OK, I could just check for `null` as @Ashalynd suggested.